# How can I use SPFolder.WelcomePage?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, folder

I found that I can set this property for any folder in a library. But what does it do? I thought I would get redirected to this welcome page when I click in the folder. Instead nothing is happening.

Does anyone know if this property can be used somehow? I'm intrigued to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That property is used by Publishing sites to set the Home Page.

```
SPWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage
```

You can also use similar technic to set List welcome page

```
SPList.RootFolder.WelcomePage
```

We can't have a welcome page for each of the sub folders. Folder is a container of items and it doesn't make sense to have a separate welcome page  for folders.

Comment: oh well, you are probably right

Answer (score 0):

Gets or sets the URL to which users are redirected when they browse to the folder.

> A string that contains the URL to which users are redirected. For a
>   wiki site, the string specifies a site-relative URL, for example,
>   MyWikiFolder/MyWelcomePage.aspx, but for a wiki library, the string
>   specifies a folder-relative URL, for example, MyWelcome.aspx.

[SPFolder.WelcomePage Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.welcomepage(v=office.14).aspx)

**Example**

```
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server:100/sites/InternetSite/");

SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

SPFolder folder = web.RootFolder;

folder.WelcomePage = "TestWiki/Hello1.aspx";

folder.Update();
```